# Execute task TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I’m trying to make an NPM script for two TSC tasks, I use TSC locally, not globally (it's not an option to switch to global), and I want to know how to run those two tasks without using the CTRL + SHIFT + B of Visual Studio Code, does anyone know how?

I have been trying "npx tsc build" or "npx tsc watch" but none works, I also tried "npx tsc: build - tsconfig.build.json" and it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal command:

```
tsc -p ./path/to/tsconfig.json
```

Compiles the TypeScript project located at the specified path.